# How would I connect a RESTful API to my mobile app in Dreamweaver?

Tags: javascript, rest, cordova, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver with PhoneGap to develop a cross-platform mobile app.

I need to connect to a RESTful API because the index page has a form for a patient to log-in using their name and DOB.
This is my first mobile app so I am not really sure what to do for this.

Since Dreamweaver supports HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, I'm assuming I would just need to use AJAX GET method to create an instance of user where the name is equal to the name given by the client on the form.. and then validate authenticity using JavaScript?

Any advice would be super helpful. I have tried to find tutorials on consuming API web services, but I must have some syntax wrong because I can't find anything on API connection to a mobile app in Dreamweaver.

Comment: i am posting a sample code for u in this u can find how a service call is made using ajax in cordova  `function addData() {
    var e = $("#dpd_name").val();

   
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: trak.Settings.Data,
       
        data: "clientId=" +e+ "",

        success: function (resp) {
            
            navigator.notification.alert("Data Saved Successfully");

        },
        error: function (e) {
         
            navigator.notification.alert("Invalid data");
            
        }
    });
};

`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for Ajax POST/GET calls in Cordova-

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://yourWebURL.php",
  type: "POST", //change it to GET if you want
  data: {id : menuId}, //variables for GET/POST call
  dataType: "html"
});

request.done(function(msg) { //request successful 
    console.log( msg );
    alert(msg);

});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) { //request failed
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```